# SmartGwt RPC service (No source code is available for type com.server.GreetingServiceImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module?)

Tags: java, rpc, smartgwt

I'm getting an error when I'm trying to access server-side's GreetingServiceImpl class and try to use a function of it in client-side.

ERROR: No source code is available for type com.demo1.server.GreetingServiceImpl; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Here is the GreetingServiceImpl:

public class GreetingServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
        GreetingService {

```
public LinkedList<String> greetServer() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Verify that the input is valid.

    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

    try {
        File file = getLog();
        Parse parse = new Parse(file);
        list = parse.callControlRequest();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return list;
}

public File getLog() throws IOException {
   //doing something
}
```

}

and I'm trying to use it in client-side like:

GreetingServiceImpl resultList = new GreetingServiceImpl(); //this is where I am getting error

greetingService.greetServer(new AsyncCallback>() {

```
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialogBox
            .setText("Remote Procedure Call - Failure");
    dialogBox.center();

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LinkedList<String> result) {

            result=resultList.greetServer(); // this is where I am trying to get the output of it
        }
    });;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use classes from your server side on client side. To use GreetingService you should instantiate it's async part:

```
GreetingServiceAsync greetingService = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
```

then you could use greetingService variable to call methods in GreetingServiceImpl - you can't use or refer GreetingServiceImpl directly on client side, so line

```
GreetingServiceImpl resultList = new GreetingServiceImpl();
```

is illegal - remove it.

Also you can generate default gwt application and look how it's done there or look at DynaTable sample provided with gwt library: gwt-dir/samples/DynaTable.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I got the idea, it works now. Thanks.